# Upgrade spring-data-jpa to 1.11.13.RELEASE order by throw exception

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I upgrade the **spring-data-jpa to 1.11.13.RELEASE**, beacuse this commit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/5f87c6766863072d761cb02f278b13c8631e655f,

This method:

```
List<AppVersion> findByDeviceAndPlatformAndIVersionGreaterThanOrderByIVersionDesc(Device device,App app,Integer versioncode);
```

the order by could not find the property, this is the property:

```
private Integer iVersion;
```

throw this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [IVersion] on this
 ManagedType [cn.com.open.entity.BaseEntityRoot]    at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManageType.java:128)
    at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113)
    at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:111)
    at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:111)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:571)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:548)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:501)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:195)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:143)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:52)
    at
 org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at
 org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:133)
    at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:72)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug when parsing the OrderBy clause when the second character of the attribute is uppercase.

You should file a bug report with Spring Data JPA:

https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA/issues/DATAJPA-1397?filter=allopenissues

In the meanwhile you either must change the name of the attribute or write the query in a @Query annotation.